# Chess alpha beta returning wrong move for the board

Tags: java, chess, minimax

I am trying to implement a chess game with alpha beta pruning. The following is almost working, but it returns wrong moves.

For example, the following can occur.

*White (user) to move, white king position - a1 / Black (computer), black king position - h1*

*White moves its king from a1 - a2, then black return the move g2 - g1???*

[image: Example]

It appears that the computer returns a move for the wrong node (board representation), as if the best evaluation of a given board position is not being propagated all the way back up the tree. So in one of the simulated positions explored, the computer "imagines" its king moving to g2 and then returns the move to be made from this position, not realising that this position is a simulated position and not the representation of the actual board (the root node?).

**How can I correct the code to make the computer return a move for the actual board representation and not one of the simulations by mistake?**

Thank you.

Initial call `alphaBeta(3, ChessEngine.invertBoard(ChessEngine.board), -10000, 10000, true);`

```
private static int alphaBetaEvaluate = 0;
private static int alphaBetaSelectedSquare = 0;
private static int alphaBetaMoveToSquare = 0;
public static int alphaBeta(int depth, char[] board, int alpha, int beta, boolean maxPlayer) {

    //create a copy of the board
    char[] boardCopy = board.clone();

    //if terminal state has not been met, keep searching
    if (maxPlayer == true && depth > 0) {

        //for all of the moves that max can make
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int move : ChessEngine.getValidMoves(i, boardCopy)) {

                //make the move
                boardCopy[move] = boardCopy[i];
                boardCopy[i] = '.';

                alphaBetaEvaluate = rating(board, boardCopy, i, move);

                //store the best move to make
                int temp = alphaBeta(--depth, ChessEngine.invertBoard(boardCopy), -10000, 10000, false);
                if (temp > alpha) {
                    alphaBetaSelectedSquare = i;
                    alphaBetaMoveToSquare = move;           
                    alpha = temp;
                }

                //reset the board for the next simulated move
                boardCopy = board.clone();

                if (beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    } else if (maxPlayer == false && depth > 0) {

        //for all of the moves that min can make
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int move : ChessEngine.getValidMoves(i, boardCopy)) {

                //make the move
                boardCopy[move] = boardCopy[i];
                boardCopy[i] = '.';
                beta = Math.min(beta, alphaBeta(--depth, ChessEngine.invertBoard(boardCopy), -10000, 10000, true));

                //reset the board for the next simulated move
                boardCopy = board.clone();

                if (beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return beta;
    }
    return alphaBetaEvaluate;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your rating algorithm is working correctly? It would be worth manually checking the value it is returning for each of the possible positions in the 2 king situation. I would imagine it would be difficult for the algorithm to distinguish between positions (given there's no winning strategy with just 2 kings on the board).

Comment: Another debugging suggestion I have is to change your rating algorithm to something artificial and simple such as distance from edge. This is a way of ruling out the possibility that rating is at fault - if the kings still repeat moves then you know the alpha-beta must be a fault.

Comment: Hi sprinter, I just adjusted the rating to only consider the position the king is moving to, but it still returned g2 - g1. I am confident it is an alpha-beta issue, but i'm still not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont get your implementation after all. First of all what you want to do is create a tree. A decision tree and propagates the decision up. You want to maximize your evaluation and also expect that the enemy will select the move that minimizes your evaluation in return.

So inverting the board does not sound so reasonable for me unless you know that the evaluation you do uppon the situation is correctly adjusting.

Another serious problem for me is that you always call the min/max for the next move with -10k and 10k as the bounderies for alpha and beta. This way your algorithm does not 'learn' from previous moves.

What you need is to check the algorithm again (wikipedia for instance, which I used) and see that they use alpha and beta being modified by former evaluation. This way the calculation in higher depth can firstly stop and secondly evaluate the best move better.

I am no expert in this. its decades ago when I wrote my implementation and I used something different.

Another idea is not to use min and max within the same method but use the min and max methods instead. It makes it more likely you spot other defects.

Also do not use two kings for evaluation. There is no goal in that. Two kings are random, cant win. One thing might be two knights or four queens and alike. It is not so random and you can see the queens dancing around without being able to catch each other. Or use three knights versus a single queen.

And try to create yourself some unit tests around your other parts. Just to insure that the parts are working correctly independently. And why are you using characters? Why not using enums or objects. You can reuse the objets for each field (its more like kinds of figures).

But anyhow this is style and not algorithm correctness.

Comment: Yay an answer :)

Changing the call with the alphabeta function to use the alpha beta values instead of +/-10000 seemed to have fixed the problem. Big mistake on my behalf that I just wasn’t seeing.
As for the two kings, I know this was not ideal, but it more consistently produced the error in comparison to other board setups.
I will keeping testing to see if everything is working now, since I changed the alpha beta values.
If it is, then you won a bounty! – which I will accept in a few days.

Comment: :) . . . . . . . . . . .